# Django (REST Framework) - How to add fields to queryset iteration

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I need some advice for making a query in Django (DRF).

I'm trying to make a queryset for Products, where every Product gets a field "images" with all the Images (Files) for that product (coupled using ProductImage model), but I can't figure out how to add the field.

Below is my ProductViewSet

```
class ProductViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = ProductSerializer
    queryset = Product.objects.all()

    def get_queryset(self): 
        queryset = Product.objects.all()
        product_list = []

        # iterate over all products
        for product in queryset:

            # find Image ids for product
            image_ids = list(ProductImage.objects.filter(product=product.id).values_list('image', flat=True))
            images = []

            # iterate over images and add to images list
            for image_id in image_ids:
                image = list(File.objects.filter(id=image_id).all())
                images.append(image)

            # add images field to product
            # product['images'] = images # "TypeError: 'Product' object does not support item assignment"
            product.images = images # Doesn't do anything.

            # add product to product list
            product_list.append(product)

        return product_list
```

I've tried to do the following to add the field "images":

```
        product['images'] = images
```

which gives the error "TypeError: 'Product' object does not support item assignment"

```
        product.images = images
```

which doesn't do anything...

Could anyone point me in the right direction? Any tips on how to make this query in a better way are also welcome!

Answer (score 1):

Does your 'Product' model have an existing 'images' field with the correct data type?

If not, you won't be able to update it with a list of FileObjects.

A better solution might be a many-to-one model relationship between 'ProductImage' and 'Product'.

Then, Django will be better able to automagically return your images through the ORM rather than complicated bespoke queries.
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/db/examples/many_to_one/

Comment: Product does not have an existing 'images' field, I want to add this field in the response of the query. I've thought about it, but I'm using the File model for other things as well, so I don't want to strictly relate it to Product. ProductImage uses a Product and a File object (where the file is an image file). Is there really no way to just add a field in the viewset? It can't be that difficult?

Comment: I've now made ProductImage its own model, with Product as foreign key. However, I still don't know how to add "images" as a field of Product in a query.

Comment: If you could share your models, it would help a lot.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to give an exact answer without seeing the other models, but if you write a more robust query, and use [annotate](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/querysets/#annotate), the annotated fields will be accessible on both the filtersets and serializers.

Comment: What would you like to know about my models? I didn't add them because I didn't think it was very relevant to my issue. I've played around with annotate but I'm not sure how it works, I can only find examples with Count(). Could you give me an example?

Answer (score 0):

try to use a dict, product_list = {}  product_list[product] = images

remove

```
        product.images = images # Doesn't do anything.

        # add product to product list
        product_list.append(product)
```